# jQuery Odd: CSS or jQ selector?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, filter, css-selectors

There are two easy ways to select odd rows in a table with jQuery, using the `:odd` filter, or the `:nth-child(odd)` selector;

```
$('table tr').filter(':odd')
$('table tr:nth-child(odd)')
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks of each method? Mainly wondering in terms of execution speed and browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method with `.filter(':odd')` is most probably slower, because it uses an additional method call and it uses a non-standard selector. jQuery has to handle everything in this case.

The second method will potentially be faster in modern browsers that implement the Selectors API and support the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, as your given selector is valid CSS, so the selector will be evaluated by a modern browser's selector engine rather than jQuery. In other browsers, though, I have no idea, but I'd still bet on the second method being fractionally more efficient because there is at least one less method call.

**Either way, there is no real (practical) benefit or drawback to either method.** In fact, I'm only answering theoretically — I don't really have any benchmarks to back anything up. There is also no need to worry about browser compatibility as jQuery polyfills the `:nth-child()` selector for older browsers anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if jQuery would handle the selector if it wasn't supported by the browser. Do you have a link to source for that, just out of interest? :)

Comment: @Joe: It's all in the front page :)

Answer (score 1):

Browser support shouldn't be an issue, as jQuery works well in all modern-ish browsers: http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility