# nth-child(odd) not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does every row have a red background when I'm using `nth-child(odd)`?

```
<div id="ClientTable">
    <div class="ClientTableHeaderRow"><span class="ClientTableHeaderColumn">Full Name</span></div>
    <div class="ClientTableRow"><span class="ClientName">Umpa Beeson</span></div>
    <div class="ClientTableRow"><span class="ClientName">Umpa Beeson</span></div>
    <div class="ClientTableRow"><span class="ClientName">Umpa Beeson</span></div>
    <div class="ClientTableRow"><span class="ClientName">Umpa Beeson</span></div>
</div>​
```

```css
#ClientTable    {position: relative;
                 display: table;
                 margin-top: 20px;
                 width: 100%;}

#ClientTable:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#FF0000;}                 

.ClientTableHeaderRow, .ClientTableRow {display: table-row; }
.ClientTableHeaderRow {font-weight: bold;}
.ClientTableHeaderRow span, .ClientTableRow span {display: table-cell;}​
```

[View the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMR2K/3/)

The expected result is every other row to be red. Instead, as you can see, every row is red.
P.S. Umpa is my cat.

Comment: Wow, epic edit.  Thanks @animuson.  I'll try to be more verbose here next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be setting `ClientTableRow` class, like so:

```
.ClientTableRow:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#FF0000;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gMR2K/4/

**EDIT**

As also explained by animuson, you need to apply the `:nth-child`selector to the element itself, not the parent. The name of the selector can lead one to think it will apply the styling to the children of the selected element, when actually the style is applied to n-th child of the selected element, across the whole document.

Also, if you're worried about browser compatibility you can also do this with JavaScript. Here's an example using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready()
{
    $(".ClientTableRow:nth-child(odd)").addClass("redBackground");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gMR2K/10/

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193435/jquery-odd-css-or-jq-selector) by BoltClock: jQuery "polyfills the :nth-child() selector for older browsers anyway."

Comment: Yes, I understand it now, but it still makes no sense (if that makes sense).  :)

Comment: @Scott Beeson: `:nth-child()` is a pseudo-class. Pseudo-classes apply to elements in the same way that IDs and regular classes do: not to an element's children, but to the element itself.

Answer (score 7):

`nth-child` applies to the actual element, not its children. `#ClientTable` is the 1st (and only) child of its parent. Therefore, it has a red background. You need to be applying the nth-child to the elements inside that division.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you want?:

http://jsfiddle.net/gMR2K/6/

```
#ClientTable div:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#FF0000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

and that only works in the better browsers. IE 8 and below don't get it. But, you can use jQuery to make it work everywhere or (painfully) add a class to the odd rows.

Comment: Is part of your first sentence missing?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a small mistake

.someclassA .someclassB: nth-child(odd){
You can see as above there is one space between someclassB: and nth-child. thats it.. By deleting that space it started working :)